# PDO in Class good practice and guidance

Tags: php, class, pdo

HI all i've been struggling for a week or two trying to get my head around the whole PDO, singleton or not MVC and more stuff. I've been coding now for 3 months and i'd like to know if i've finally got this right.

I'm building a simple school application for classes grades etc... and have made a class called sections which I've now incorporated a PDO into. It work and functions as id like so far but before i make more classes in the same fashion i'd like to know if there are any mistakes and how i could improve things. I didn't right the DB class myself although I wrote everything else.

```
class pdoDB {

/*** Declare instance ***/
private static $db = NULL;

/**
*
* the constructor is set to private so
* so nobody can create a new instance using new
*
*/
private function __construct() {
/*** maybe set the db name here later ***/
}

/**
*
* Return DB instance or create intitial connection
*
* @return object (PDO)
*
* @access public
*
*/
public static function getInstance() {

 if (!self::$db)
{
self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=attendance_ksu','root','root');;
self::$db-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
return self::$db;
}

/**
*
* Like the constructor, we make __clone private
* so nobody can clone the instance
*
*/
private function __clone(){
}

} /*** end of class ***/
```

Now my sections class.

```
class Section  {


// if protected can't loop through on html page into table
    // I don't want to make getter method for each attribute.
    // all data will be coming from the db

public $id;
public $section_number;
public $subject;
public $classroom;
public $level_id;
public $shift;
public $course;
public $campus;
public $times;
public $academic_year;
public $start_date;
public $end_date;
public $max_st_number;
public $status;

// retrieve all sections in db

public static function get_all_sections() {

try {

    // maybe a waste of time doing this bit?? not sure!! the " if(!isset($db)) "

if(!isset($db)) {
$db = pdoDB::getInstance();

/*** echo a message saying we have connected for testing reasons only ***/
echo 'Connected to database <br />';
}

/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sections";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$objs = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Section');

// 1. return the complete array of data so I can loop through it later

return $objs;  

// 2. Or echo out a loop immediately where this method is called

   /*

foreach ($objs as $section) {
echo "Section:" . $section->section_number . " | " . 
     "Subject: {$section->subject}" . "<br/>";
}

    */

$db = null;   
    }

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

}


// Get the section details by id from db
// will be passed via the URL as $_GET

public static function get_section_by_id($id) {

try {

if(!isset($db)) {
$db = pdoDB::getInstance();

/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
echo 'Connected to database<br />';
}   
     /*** prepare the SQL statement ***/
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE id = :id");

/*** bind the paramaters ***/
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

/*** execute the prepared statement ***/
$stmt->execute();

/*** fetch the results and give it a class ***/
$section = $stmt->fetchObject('section');
return $section;

$db = null;   
    }

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}   

}
}
```

I entend to just call the get_all_sections() method on a page and loop through the results into a table. other pages will also be done in this method. Without extending my learning curve into MVC etc... is this an acceptable method and am i heading in the right direction?

EG:

```
<?php
// some code
$sections = Section::get_all_sections();

// any other necessary code
?>

<html> 
<body>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-highlight" id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Section Number</th>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Course</th>
<th>Students</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Campus</th>
<th>Classroom</th>
<th>Shift</th>
<th>Start date</th>
<th>End date</th>
<th>Teacher</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php 
$key =  1;
foreach($sections as $section) {
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $key++ ?></td>
<td><a href=""><?php echo $section->section_number ?></a> </td>
<td><?php echo $section->subject ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $section->course ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $section->no_students ?> sts</td>
<td><?php echo $section->level_id ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $section->campus ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $section->classroom ?></td>
<td><?php echo $section->shift ?> </td>
<td><?php echo date("d-M-Y",strtotime($section->start_date ))?></td>
<td><?php echo date("d-M-Y",strtotime($section->end_date ))?></td>
<td>

<?php 
if($section->username  =="")
{
echo "<a href=\"add_section_teacher.php?id=".urlencode($section->id )."&section_number=".urlencode($section->section_number )."\">Not assigned</a>";

} else {
echo "<a href=\"edit_section_teacher.php?ts_id=".urlencode($section->ts_id )."\">";
echo $section->username ; 
echo "</a>";
}       
?>  
</td>
<td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $section->id ; ?>" 
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete section <?php echo $section->section_number ; ?> ?');">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<? }?></tbody>
</table>
```

thanks in advance for any feedback and advice. I want to learn this correctly so any feedabck that is detailed :) would be appreciated as the objective here is to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your PDO factory is Ok I think.
Your class section is not OK as it does not respect the Single Responsability Principle.

Section should be only a class with the attributes, getters and setters if needed and some computing methods. No link to database has to be there. You should use the Repository pattern to put bdd access method like find, findAll...

Then you should call your repository in your controller.

```
class SectionRepository{
    public function findAll(){
       $db = pdoDB::getInstance();
       $result = $bd->query(SELECT * FROM sections);
       return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,Section);  
    }
}
```

About PDO Factory, that you are using :

```
class PDOFactory{
    private static $connection = null;
    public static function getConnection(){
        if(self::$connection === null){
             self::$connection = new PDO();//here you can use a config file if you want
             self::$connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return self::$connection;
}
```

It is not a real singleton as there is no matter of private construct (that is impossible to overload in php) and becaus PDOFactory does not extends PDO but the behaviour is quite the same.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i don't know anything about the Repository pattern. I just want to get this code working in the easiest acceptable way. I could spend weeks reading about different patterns and never get anything done or done correctly. How can I fix my section class to respect the singleton as I've seen people include db connections in there classes as i have. what pattern are they using? thanks

Comment: I gave you the way to implement repository pattern... It is really simple :
Your entity one one hand, your repository that deals with your entity on the other hand. 
In your controller you just say `$rep = new SectionRepository(); $rep->findAll()`

Comment: about singleton, most of time, you will prefer a factory that ensure you've got only one instance than a singleton.
It's allmost the same, be the code is a bit different. (1 world or two) I give it to you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answer by Artragis is indeed the way to go (longterm), I feel the pain of the OP'er struggling to wrap his mind aroun the whole OOP-mystery - I have been battling this now on and off for the past two years without really getting anywhere.

My observations as to his simple Section-class:

- The singleton pattern is ok
- The usage of the singleton is not ok: the
  singleton itself is designed to be 'instantiated' (probably wrong
  choice of words) only once and then to remain open as long as it is
  needed.

I suggest to do the following:

- Remove the test to check if $db isset - the singleton only creates a connection if one is not already present
- Remove the unsetting of the $db variable - just leave the connection open until garbage collection passes by
- One optional step would be to inject your $db_handle into the Section-class (which is easiest via the Constructor) - this would make your Section-class only loosely coupled with the pdoDB-class (okay, okay - maybe you need an intermediary interface that is implemented by the pdoDB-class first, but you get the point) and easier to test